# How to get next auto increment value from access database in c# during insert statement

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

I am currently entering data from a Windows Form Application written in C#.  My Database is a Microsoft Access Database. Everything is working fine accept I keep getting errors for duplicating my Primary Key value.  I have been digging around the internet for a while and haven't found much pertaining to my issue.

My current table setup is below:

```
Field Name     Data
-------------------
ID             AutoNumber
MonsterName    Text
Drop           Text
AmountDropped  Text
```

And my current SQL Query is below:

```
"INSERT INTO MonsterDrops (MonsterName, Drop, AmountDropped) VALUES ('" +
Monsters.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString() + "','" + DropName + "'," + Amount + ")"
```

This gives me the error: "Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement"

I am executing the query with this function:

```
private void executeNonQuery(string query)
    {
        //create a new connection and pass in config settings for it
        OleDbConnection db = new OleDbConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DFUWDBConnectionString);
        try
        {
        //Open the DB
        db.Open();

            try
            {
            //create a new command object
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

            //set the command to be your query
            command.CommandText = query;

            //set the DB for the query to be performed on
            command.Connection = db;

            //execute the insert
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        db.Close();
    }
}
```

I read that you don't have to include the AutoNumber field if Identity is set to true, not sure if mine is set that way or not.  How can I get the AutoNumber function to work while running a SQL Query???

Thanks!

Comment: I edited my question.  My SQL Query says I have a syntax error...  Not sure what I am doing wrong now...  I even changed to hard coded values for testing: "INSERT INTO MonsterDrops (MonsterName, Drop, AmountDropped) VALUES ('BOOGYMAN', 'BOOGERS', 1)" still provides syntax error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-number facilitates you to not bother about getting next value. AutoNumber should not be offering you any problem in insert as you are not using it field set, it gets next value automatically for insertion.

First you Try

```
"INSERT INTO MonsterDrops (MonsterName, Drop, AmountDropped) VALUES 
('BOOGYMAN', 'BOOGERS', '1')";
```

Then Try this one

```
"INSERT INTO MonsterDrops (MonsterName, Drop, AmountDropped) VALUES
 ('" + Monsters.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString() + "','" + DropName + "'
,'" + Amount + ")"'"
```

If you find problem in the 2nd one then you have straight away problem in the values you are getting

Otherwise if you get problem even in the first query, then you should try this way

Make your ID field `Number` instead of auto-number and try

```
"INSERT INTO MonsterDrops (ID,MonsterName, Drop, AmountDropped) VALUES 
(2222, 'BOOGYMAN', 'BOOGERS', '1')";
```

If you get succeeded this way, then you have to read more about auto-number and you will easily fix your problem, If you get problem even with this one, I am ready to help further.

**Edit**
From comments: Change your `Drop` named field to `Drop111` or something other than `Drop`. Because, the `Drop` is keyword in SQL.

Comment: This did not fix my issue... I will edit my post with how I am executing the query.

Comment: Okay well if I add a hard coded ID in, it works just fine: INSERT INTO MonsterDrops VALUES (1, 'BROWNIE', 'GOLD', '1')

Comment: @Flappy Is there any option you may see set `isIdentity` to `true`. If yes do it.

Comment: Here is the weird part:  It works just fine IF I do not include the columns in the INSERT state.  Meaning that this one works: "INSERT INTO MonsterDrops VALUES (2222, '" + monster + "', '" + DropName + "', " + Amount + ")" and this one does not: "INSERT INTO MonsterDrops (ID, MonsterName, Drop, AmountDropped) VALUES (2222, '" + monster + "', '" + DropName + "', " + Amount + ")"

Comment: YES! That worked! Thank you!  Didn't even think about keywords... Changed Drop to DropName and it works now.  Thanks!

Comment: You solved your problem yourself actually :) Well done. It is always pleasing to interact/guide with a person, who tries more than the consulted people her/himself

Answer (score 0):

I belive you need to set autoincrement somethink like

```
ALTER TABLE MonsterDrops
   ALTER COLUMN ID AUTOINCREMENT(1001,1)
```

basically replace 1001 with your last ID and you want to increment your next insert by 1