# error while accessing database using insert into statement in C#

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, odbc, ms-access-2010

I am facing same problem as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017526/how-to-get-next-auto-increment-value-from-access-database-in-c-sharp-during-inse).only problem is that i am having the fields as follows

```
Field Name     Data
-------------------
ID             AutoNumber
username       Text
password       Text
```

now I don't know if any of the word username,password is keyword in ODBC.
I googled for it and many anwsers says the none of it is keyword in ODBC.
I am using ms access.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: `this one` link faced more problem. So, can you tell your problem one by one.

Comment: @UdanPirappu when i try to execute insert into Users values(1,'nikhil','mehta') it works fine form C#.but insert into Users(username,password) values('nikhil','mehta') gives syntax error in insert into statement and it works fine in ms access

Comment: But, In SQLite your code worked. In SQLite, I set some option for `ID` Field such as `NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY, AUTOINCREMENT, UNIQUE, DEFAULT 1`. Likewise, may be you put some option for your `ID` field.

Comment: @UdanPirappu i have tried may ways to do it but gives same error.Can you tell me if there any issue while accessing ms acces databse outside of ms access i.e. programatically.

Comment: Try my answer!...May be you'll get answer...

Answer (score 1):

`Password` is a reserved word. Bracket that field name to avoid confusing the db engine.

Insert into Users (Username, [Password]) values ('nikhil','mehta');