# Auto Increasing ID in MS Access Database using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString =
         "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=d:\\NewProject\\MainData.accdb;Persist Security Info=false";
        string query1 = "select BlogId from BlogTable where UserName=@username";
        OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(query1, con);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox1.Text);
        con.Open();
        int id =(int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar()+1;
      string query2="insert into BlogTable values(id,@1,@2,@3)";        
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query2, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", TextBox1.Text);
        if(RadioButton1.Checked)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", RadioButton1.Text);
        if (RadioButton2.Checked)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", RadioButton2.Text);
        if (RadioButton2.Checked)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", RadioButton3.Text);
        if (RadioButton2.Checked)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", RadioButton4.Text);
        if (RadioButton2.Checked)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", RadioButton5.Text);
        if (RadioButton2.Checked)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", RadioButton6.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", TextArea1.Text);

        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (i >= 1)
            Label1.Text = "Record Saved";
        else
            Label1.Text = "Record not Saved";

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

In my MS Access database I've set my `id` type to Autonumber though it still does not increase automatically. What do I do?

With the above code it returns an error that one of the parameter does not have value.

My table looks like this:

- `BlogId`: AutoNumber
- `Username`: Text
- `Category`: Text
- `Blog`: Text

Comment: Do you get an error? or what does it insert now?

Comment: You shall not insert the _id_ if it is an autonumber.

Comment: it doesnt insert anything and shows error that one of the parameter does not have value

Comment: you are right i tried it already but it didnt help

Comment: this might also mean another value is empty and it has nothing to do with the AI id

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get next auto increment value from access database in c# during insert statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017526/how-to-get-next-auto-increment-value-from-access-database-in-c-sharp-during-inse)

Comment: no it does not, ive seen all the possible questions for this

Comment: Please provide the full error

Comment: No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: `...BlogTable values(id,@1,@2...` - in your query "id" is not the `id` variable. It is trying to pass literally "id" as a value. That is only one problem here. If you are using auto increment id then don't try to insert the id, and never do a +1 to get "the next" value. Figure out your main problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should omit the Autonumber field from the `insert` statement, and only insert values for the other fields, e.g.:

```
string query2="insert into BlogTable (Field1, Field2, Field3) values(@1,@2,@3)";
```

Change `Field1`, `Field2`, & `Field3` to the names of the fields to be populated with the values held by parameters `@1`, `@2`, & `@3`.

You also seem to have a number of typos here:

```
if (RadioButton1.Checked)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", RadioButton1.Text);
if (RadioButton2.Checked)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", RadioButton2.Text);
if (RadioButton2.Checked) // <---------------------------- Should this be RadioButton3?
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", RadioButton3.Text);
if (RadioButton2.Checked) // <---------------------------- Should this be RadioButton4?
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", RadioButton4.Text);
if (RadioButton2.Checked) // <---------------------------- Should this be RadioButton5?
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", RadioButton5.Text);
if (RadioButton2.Checked) // <---------------------------- Should this be RadioButton6?
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", RadioButton6.Text);
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this line of code:

```
string query2="insert into BlogTable values(id,@1,@2,@3)";
```

to this:

```
string query2="insert into BlogTable values(@1,@2,@3)";
```

The reason your database query is not working, is that you are specifying that you want to insert an id by doing: `values(id, .....)` but then you don't add a value for it - which causes it to send a null value. When you want to use auto-increment(AI) for the id column the DB expects that you do not provide a value yourself, which is null in your case.

Comment: it is not increasing automatically

Comment: Then there is something wrong in your database setup, which I can not see from what you have posted

Comment: There's not. You can't omit columns if you don't specify which columns you're inserting into.

Comment: Well there is something wrong, you can't just exclude a whole part of the setup - because you think it can't be wrong

Comment: i have inserted one record into the table putting 1 on the place of id, it was successful but i thought after removing 1 from values it would automatically start increasing the id, id didn't.

Comment: Please provide the full error, if possible also the creation of your table

Comment: No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: Then you have not set auto increment properly, you have to show me more code. Like the creation of the table and the real error you are getting